# Active record query according to data in associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in my rails app ConfirmRequest.rb and Booking.rb. 
These models are associated with each other with this configration:

```
class ConfirmRequest < ActiveRecord::Base       
    has_one :booking
end


class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :confirm_request
end
```

So, I want to define 2 variables first which contains the confirm_requests for which booking has been created and other for which booking has not been created  How can I define these variable in rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following queries:

```
ConfirmRequest.where(id: Booking.pluck(:confirm_request_id))
ConfirmRequest.where.not(id: Booking.pluck(:confirm_request_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable as in a class variable ? A scope can give you that data you may create a class variable which uses that scope(not required though, scope is sufficient IMO). If you want to define a scope in ConfirmRequest to return records for which Booking has been created ? In that case

```
scope :has_booking, where("booking_id IS NOT NULL)
```

For Booking not created

```
scope :has_no_booking, where(:booking_id => nil)
```